# Using the recursion theorem to construct a sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be any set. For any sets $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in X$, let $S(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be a non-empty subset of $X$ (that is, $S(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is a subset that depends on sets  $x_1,\cdots,x_n$).

Using the [Recursion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem), how can I construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{n+1}\in S(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

---

I tried to use the axiom of choice to construct a convenient function in order to use the recursion theorem, however I failed.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Without restriction, it may easily be the various $S(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ are unrelated to each other, making it unlikely to even have a definition of the larger set $X$ of the recursion theorem, on which its $f:X \to X$ is defined, much less a definition of what a particular output value of $f$ might be.

Comment: @coffeemath You may assume that the sets $S(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ are contained in a set $X$.

Comment: So $S$ is a function that takes any *finite sequence* from $X$ and returns a nonempty subset of $X$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You can interpret $S$ in this way.

Comment: You say "I tried to use the axiom of choice to construct a convenient function in order to use the recursion theorem, however I failed." Hmm well let's see... you have a function from finite sequences to nonempty subsets of $X,$ and you have a choice function, which is a function on the nonempty subsets of $X$....

Answer (score 2):

I think the seeming difficulty here has to do with "strong induction" vs. "weak induction."

Here's how one would like to solve the problem: Let $C$ be a choice function on the non-empty subsets of $X.$  Let $x_1$ be any member of $X,$ and define $x_{n+1}$ to be $C(S(x_1,\dots,x_n)).$

This works, but the definition by recursion here needs to be the so-called "strong" form in which $F(n)$ is defined in terms of all the $F(k)$ for $k<n.$ However, the Recursion Theorem link that you provided is the "weak" form that only allows using the one previous value (plus there’s the  base case, of course).

But it's easy to get around this while using only the "weak" form, as you seem to have intended:

Use weak induction (as in your Recursion Theorem link) to define a sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that each $t_n$ is itself a finite sequence $\langle z_1, \dots, z_n\rangle$ of length $n$ of members of $X.$ The definition proceeds as follows:

• $t_1$ is any $1$-element sequence from $X.$

• Given $t_n,$ write it in the form $\langle z_1, \dots, z_n\rangle$, and then define $t_{n+1}$ to be the following sequence of length $n+1:$ $$t_{n+1}=\langle z_1, \dots, z_n, C(S(z_1, \dots, z_n))\rangle.$$ (This defines $t_{n+1}$ in terms of just $t_n,$ without regard for earlier values of $t_k.$ This is what you need in order to apply the weak form of definition by induction.)

Note that the finite sequences $t_n$ all cohere: if $m<n$ and $t_n$ is the finite sequence $\langle z_1,\dots,z_n\rangle,$ then $t_m$ is the finite sequence $\langle z_1,\dots,z_m\rangle.$

So if we define $x_n$ for $n\ge 1$ to be the $n^\text{th}$ member of the finite sequence $t_n,$ this sequence will have the desired property.